# typeahead.js prefetch doesn't work

Tags: jquery, prefetch, typeahead.js

I can't get the prefetch function in typeahead.js to work, it works just fine with the local data though. I first tried linking to a servlet returning json objects or lists, but after a while I gave up on that and started checking the provided examples. So their examples links to pages that look like this:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json
However, my script doesn't even work when I link it to that page even if I do exactly the same thing as they do. I tried copying that file over to my local workspace and linking to it there to no avail. To check if it even were making any calls I made my servlet crash every time it got a get request, and sure enough it crashed when I ran my autocomplete example page so it isn't a cache problem. I tried downgrading jquery to 1.9.1, but that didn't work either(currently using 1.10). I tried using different versions of typeahead.js. I tried using internet explorer as well as google chrome to see if the error was there.

There must be something vital that I am missing, as I have exhausted every source of errors I could think of. Others don't seem to have any problems getting this to work.

Here is the code I use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typeahead.js-bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="typeahead" placeholder="test" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {$('.typeahead').typeahead({  
        name: "Auto"  ,
        ttl_ms: 10000,                                                 
        prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json',
        //local: ['abc', 'acd', 'ade', 'bcd]                                                  
});});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

It seems the issue is related to caching of the data in the browser storage.

1. You can clean your browser storage (not the browser cache).
2. You can change the dataset `name` in typeahead config to another one.
3. You can lower the `ttl` in `prefetch`. You can increase the `ttl` later, of course. See below:

   ```
   prefetch: {
       url: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json',
       ttl: 1 // in milliseconds
   },
   ```

It will be more clear if you browse the code here: http://goo.gl/TN3Gv

Comment: I found the error, the problem was that I fetched a faulty version, I think I picked a development version. When I switched to the stable one everything worked out fine. But thank you for trying!

Comment: The cacheKey it uses for local storage is actually the URL. So changing the name did no good, I had to update the prefetch URL in order for the defective cache to be cleared