# typeahead.js prefetch problems

Tags: jquery, typeahead, prefetch, typeahead.js

I'm using a typeahead.js on a Google App Engine project and having problems using prefetch.

The typeahead works fine when I use local but if I copy the same dataset to a json file and use prefetch, the typeahead does not work, i.e. no suggestions are displayed.

Here's my version of the code using local:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><input type="text" name="typeahead-example" placeholder="Type here" class="typeahead-example"></div>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./js/hogan.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./js/typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input.typeahead-example').typeahead({
                  name: 'example',
                  local: [{value: 'Abc Def', tokens: ['Abc', 'Def'], name: 'random1', val2: 'A', val3: 'B'},
                    {value: 'Def Ghi', tokens: ['Def', 'Ghi'], name: 'random2', val2: 'C', val3: 'D'},
                    {value: 'Ghi Jkl', tokens: ['Ghi', 'Jkl'], name: 'random3', val2: 'E', val3: 'F'},
                    {value: 'Jkl Mno', tokens: ['Jkl', 'Mno'], name: 'random4', val2: 'G', val3: 'H'}],
                  limit: 3,
                  valueKey: 'name',
                  template: '<p>{{value}}</p>',
                  engine: Hogan
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my version of the code using prefetch:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><input type="text" name="typeahead-example" placeholder="Type here" class="typeahead-example"></div>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./js/hogan.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./js/typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input.typeahead-example').typeahead({
                  name: 'example',
                  prefetch: {url: './json/example.json', ttl: '0'},
                  limit: 3,
                  valueKey: 'name',
                  template: '<p>{{value}}</p>',
                  engine: Hogan
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the example.json file:

```
[{value: 'Abc Def', tokens: ['Abc', 'Def'], name: 'random1', val2: 'A', val3: 'B'}, {value: 'Def Ghi', tokens: ['Def', 'Ghi'], name: 'random2', val2: 'C', val3: 'D'}, {value: 'Ghi Jkl', tokens: ['Ghi', 'Jkl'], name: 'random3', val2: 'E', val3: 'F'}, {value: 'Jkl Mno', tokens: ['Jkl', 'Mno'], name: 'random4', val2: 'G', val3: 'H'}]
```

The problem occurs in Chrome and Firefox. Debugging in chrome, I can see that the example.json file is served and received. The preview and response of the network activity for example.json shows the contents of the file in its entirety. However, on the resources section of the chrome debugger, Local Storage is empty. There are no console errors, just this message

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8000/json/example.json". jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
send jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-1.10.2.js:8282
jQuery.extend.getJSON jquery-1.10.2.js:8265
c.mixin._loadPrefetchData typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
c.mixin.initialize typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
(anonymous function) typeahead.min.js:7
jQuery.extend.map jquery-1.10.2.js:782
g typeahead.min.js:7
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.10.2.js:657
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.10.2.js:266
b.initialize typeahead.min.js:7
jQuery.fn.typeahead typeahead.min.js:7
(anonymous function) prefetch.html:14
fire jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.js:433
completed
```

With respect to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753973/typeahead-js-trouble-suggestions-not-appear), I'm not having cross domain issues and with respect to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294606/typeahead-js-prefetch-doesnt-work/17503459#17503459), I've set ttl to 0 and the problem still persists.

Any help would be appreciated.

- UPDATE *
  In response to suggestion from @NitzanShaked I added some console logging.

First I tried this and nothing registered in the console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead-example').typeahead({
      name: 'example',
      prefetch: {
        url: './json/example.json', 
        ttl: '0',
        filter: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                datum = data[i];
                console.log(datum);
            }
            return data;
        }
      },
      limit: 3,
      valueKey: 'name',
      template: '<p>{{value}}</p>',
      engine: Hogan,
    });
});
```

Then I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead-example').typeahead({
      name: 'example',
      prefetch: {url: './json/example.json', ttl: '0'},
      limit: 3,
      valueKey: 'name',
      template: '<p>{{value}}</p>',
      engine: Hogan,
    }).bind('typeahead:opened', function (obj, datum) {
                console.log(obj);
                console.log(datum);
                console.log(datum.val2);
                });
});
```

Which caused the console to log the following when I click inside the input field

```
jQuery.Event {type: "typeahead:opened", timeStamp: 1378502920480, jQuery1102039872112357988954: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: ""…}
currentTarget: input.typeahead-example tt-query
data: null
delegateTarget: input.typeahead-example tt-query
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: 3
jQuery1102039872112357988954: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: null
result: undefined
target: input.typeahead-example tt-query
timeStamp: 1378502920480
type: "typeahead:opened"
__proto__: Object
 prefetch.html:22
undefined prefetch.html:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val2' of undefined prefetch.html:24
(anonymous function) prefetch.html:24
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
jQuery.event.trigger jquery-1.10.2.js:5007
(anonymous function) jquery-1.10.2.js:5691
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.10.2.js:657
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.10.2.js:266
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery-1.10.2.js:5690
c.mixin.trigger typeahead.min.js:7
c.mixin._propagateEvent typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
d.trigger typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
c.mixin.open typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
c.mixin._openDropdown typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
d.trigger typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
c.mixin._handleFocus typeahead.min.js:7
proxy jquery-1.10.2.js:827
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle
```

Comment: Try not specifying `name` for the prefetch dataset (`"example"` in your case), just to make sure it is not brought in from local storage.

Comment: @NitzanShaked thanks for the suggestion. Tried that but didn't make a difference

Comment: Add a `filter`, then, and use `console.log` to print the parameter. See that it makes sense. If it does, try returning a dummy Datum from `filter` just to see that it works.

Comment: @NitzanShaked thanks again - updated the information above based on the suggestion

Comment: `filter` should be part of `prefetch`. Try again?

Comment: @NitzanShaked thanks for the correction - I made the change (reflected in the post above now) but still no action in the typeahead. Are you able to run on your side? Maybe something wrong with my environment somehow (Even though I've run into same problem on GAE, locally with GAE dev server and locally with python SimpleHTTPServer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is in `example.json`, as it turns out... You need to quote key names using double quotes, and all strings (e.g. in `tokens`) need to be quoted in double quotes as well.

For example, this works for me:

```
[{"value": "Abc Def", "tokens": ["Abc", "Def"], "name": "random1", "val2": "A", "val3": "B"}]
```

It would also be wise to change the `url` from `./json/example.json` to `/json/example.json` (remove the leading dot).

Comment: This did it - thanks! Strange that `local` recognized the dataset without the quotes.

Comment: I'm glad. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Accepted - still a stack exchange noob so need more rep to upvote but will do once I get there

Answer (score 6):

@diddleboo `local` recognized the dataset without the quotes because at that moment you are using **Javascript Object Literal**, and **this is not the same thing as a JSON**.

**Javascript Object Literal** is just an `object` in Javascript environment, and the language specification says that is not required double quotes for naming objects properties.

While

**JSON** stands for **JavaScript Object Notation**. It's a format for data transfer and its syntax do require double quotes for a property name. Take a look here for more about JSON definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Great added clarity on the root cause of the problem.